# Atomic operations on a single variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, relaxed-atomics

What are the possible final results for the variable `x` in the following C++ code fragment? (please answer based on what is allowed by the C++ standard and not what is currently available on different platforms)

```
// Inside Thread 0
std::atomic<int> x = {2};
// Inside Thread 1
x.fetch_sub(1,std::memory_order_relaxed)
// Inside Thread 2
x.fetch_sub(1,std::memory_order_relaxed)
```

Ideally I want `x` to be zero at the end. Is that the case, eventhough I am using `std::memory_order_relaxed`?

Edit:
To make the question more precise, is it guaranteed that
1) In Threads 1 and 2 the return value is either 0 or 1, and
2) The return value in Threads 1 and 2 are different.

Comment: Is the initialization in thread 0 executed before the other two threads are started?

Comment: @walnut Yes, of course. Assume that "the initialization in thread 0 is executed before the other two threads are started".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: `std::memory_order_relaxed` is described as:

> Relaxed operation: there are no synchronization or ordering constraints imposed on other reads or writes, only this operation's atomicity is guaranteed.

<sup>[Source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Constants)</sup>

What this effectively means is that it only guarantees atomicity. That means that the `std::atomic::fetch_sub` operation will guarantee just the atomic read-modify-write operation, no ordering whatsoever regarding other operations. This, however, does not mean that the compiler may reorder two different *atomic* read, modify and write operations (that could lead to data race, which is Undefined Behaviour). They are still **atomic**.

> Ideally I want `x` to be zero at the end. Is that the case, eventhough I am using `std::memory_order_relaxed`?

Memory order won't matter in this case. None of them will interfere with basic guarantees of atomicity. The above statement you made will hold true for *any* memory order, because it holds true, by definition, for any atomic variable which is modified in such manner (two, potentially asynchronous, subtractions from the initial value of `2`).

> To make the question more precise, is it guaranteed that 1) In both threads the return value is either `0` or `1`, and 2) The return value in Threads `1` and `2` are different.

Yes and yes, assuming that *threads return the value that `x` holds just after the `fetch_sub` call*, which is probably technically incorrect (threads *don't* return values), but I see where you are coming from here.